Can't change to Home directory on log in from console
I've been having a strange problem with my Fedora 39 install. I don't have a display manager, so the computer boots to the console. When I log in as my user, I get an error:
-- fab: /home/fab: change directory failed: Permission denied
Logging in with home = "/"

Once I'm logged in, I can cd to my home (/home/fab) and start my graphics session.
I have verified that in /etc/passwd, my home is indeed /home/fab and not /
My user "fab" owns /home/fab, the directory is rw, /home is mounted as rw, and my user can modify/delete/create files and directories in /home/fab
Have I missed something obvious? Does anybody have an idea what's going on? Thanks!
Edit: I have tried to ssh fab@machine and su - fab on this machine from the console once logged in; I tried with the fab account, and the root account; every time, I was asked for my password (I don't have ~/.ssh/authorized_keys setup), and I was directly logged in in the HOME directory, with no message of permission denied.
I also tried from another machine with ssh fab@machine, and was logged in directly in HOME again, with no permission error.
So it seems that the permission error only occurs when I log in on the console of the machine!
Furthermore, the machine from which I sshed is also under Fedora 39, and I logged in in the console (but there is also a display manager running), and I didn't get the permission error. So there is a misconfiguration on the machine which gives the error, but where?
Thanks again for the inputs!

/home/fab should be rwx. (/home as well). Please check that.

@MC68020:  While there is a mystery here that needs to be solved, the fact that the OP can cd to the directory manually and work therein suggests that there is not a permissions problem.

I would wonder about (1) a timing problem.  Does this problem happen if you wait for a minute after booting before logging in?  If you logout and login again, what happens?  (2) Non-printing character(s) in /etc/passwd.  Does cat -A /etc/passwd reveal anything interesting?  How about ls -ldb ~ ~fab "$HOME"?

@MC68020 Should mention that, for directories, the x permission means the directory  is searchable.

Yep, /home/fab is rwx for fab. I'll try the timing problem, I didn't think about that, but logging out and in again after 3 hours uptime shows the same problem. cat -A /etc/passwd doesn't show anything unusual. And ls -ldb ~ ~fab "$HOME" gives
drwxr-xr-x. 103 fab fab 28672 May  1 21:17 /home/fab/ 
drwxr-xr-x. 103 fab fab 28672 May  1 21:17 /home/fab/ 
drwxr-xr-x. 103 fab fab 28672 May  1 21:17 /home/fab/  so everything seems all right there too. Thanks for the input anyway! :)

What happens if you manually source your profile and rc-files?

user3605616 we're getting too much detail added as comments. Please edit your question to correct the errors and add the missing information. Everything relevant should be in your question so that it's easy to read. Help us to help you

the above conditions and permissions should work for default user home directory.
furthermore, i would try to debug this issue by:

using ssh [-v] [-vv] [-vvv] fab@$HOST and su commands to check if the issue persist
checking user login scripts if there might be other accounts trying to access the homedir
looking into the logs at /var/log/security and /var/log/messages for any relevant information

